# Infinite outputs of an if-else/while loop?

Tags: c++, loops

I'm a beginner programmer in C++ trying to create this practice guess-the-number game that needs to fulfill some requirements. These are:

1. Use 'flush' (I don't know what this is, help?)
2. Exit the game once the number has been guessed
3. Exit the game once a maximum of 10 guesses have been exceeded

But the problem right now is that when I enter a number, it tells me whether the entered number is higher or lower than the randomly generated correct number continuously. So if it's lower, the output is 'lowerlowerlowerlowerlowerlowerlowerlowerlower' and so forth. I  don't know what I did wrong?

Here is my code.
(X = randomly generated number, Y  = guess, Z = # of guesses)

```
int main() {
  int x , y, z;
  x = rand() % 1000 + 1;
  std::cin>>y;
  do{
    if (y > x){
      std::cout<<"higher"<< std::endl;
      z++;
    } else if (y < x) {
      std::cout<<"lower"<< std::endl;
      z++;
    } else if (y == x) {
      std::cout<<"correct"<< std::endl;
    }
  } while (y != x && z < 11);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are your expectations from code?

Answer (score 1):

Put your std::cin into the loop. You also need to set z at first and add it by 1 every time the loop runs.

```
int main() {
  srand (time(NULL));
  int x , y, z;
  x = rand() % 1000 + 1;
  z = 0;

  do{
 std::cin>>y;
    if (y > x){
      std::cout<<"higher"<< std::endl;

    } else if (y < x) {
      std::cout<<"lower"<< std::endl;

    } else if (y == x) {
      std::cout<<"correct"<< std::endl;
    }
  } while (y != x && z++ < 9);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- the variable z is not initialized

2-you are supposed to read the input everytime you loop i guess ( to read the guess )? like this

```
do{
   std::cin>> y ;
   // the rest of your loop
while(your condition);
```

Note : you should  initialize random seed before you use your random function :

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Just take input inside do-while loop.
2. Another issue initializes Z with zero. It is default initialized and can have any value.
3. Suggestion 
   initialize random seed:

```
srand (time(NULL)); // it will give 'x' every time a different value.
int  z=0; // Dont forget to do this thing.

do{
    cout<<"Enter number - "; // This thing your are missing.
    std::cin>>y;
    if (y > x){
      std::cout<<"higher"<< std::endl;
      z++;
    }
    else if (y < x) {
      std::cout<<"lower"<< std::endl;
      z++;
    }
    else if (y == x) {
      std::cout<<"correct"<< std::endl;
    }
  } while (y != x && z < 11);
  return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have undefined behavior:

```
z++;
```

`z` is used before initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing wrong a few things:

- As you must use flush operation explicitly, you must use `std::cout << std::flush;` somewhere.
- You need to get input from the user inside do-while loop body.
- You need to initialize random number generator first before using it.
- You need to initialize `z` variable to 0, because you've undefined behaviour - you're incrementing the variable which has undefined value (not initialized earlier).

Here is your code with these fixes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    int x, y, z = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));
    x = rand() % 1000 + 1;

    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    do {
        std::cin >> y;
        if(y > x) {
            std::cout << "higher" << std::endl;
            z++;
        } else if(y < x) {
            std::cout << "lower" << std::endl;
            z++;
        } else {
            std::cout << "correct" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << std::flush;
    } while(y != x && z <= 10);
    return 0;
}
```

You said you don't know what is a flush operation. This is the operation of empting output buffer (used by std::cout object internally). Normally you don't need to explicitly flush output buffer, but if you need so...